# How to navigate through Navigation View

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I have implemented the Navigation View. And it is looking beautiful and fine. I am using it on my main activity and I am working on the pre-designed principals.

**What I have done so far**

I have made the navigation view with the help of Android Studio while creating new project manual. So I have implemented and updated the navigation view with my views and strings .

now its on the Main Activity and it is working fine. I have 3 views in navigation view list , that is "Work Schedule" "About us" "Settings"

these are menu which I can click to go to other activities

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/work"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_sche"
            android:title="Work Schedule" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/about_us"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="About Us" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_tickets"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Tickets" />
         </group>

</menu>
```

Work Schedule is my Main Activity which gets opens up by default. and Contains over it.  now following is what I want

**" What I want and what Confuses me"**

1. I know I can handle clicks on these menu in my Main Activity **onNavigationItemSelected** method as shown below

> ```
>  @Override
> public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
>   {
>     // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
>
>     int id = item.getItemId();
> ```

So I can handle click in this method

but if I navigate to other activity , is it understood that the navigation view would cover that also ??

2. When I navigate to other view/Class that menu should be highlighted
3. I want when I click to menu in navigation view it should open the new activity with good transition

> Considerations

The first point is my confusion and also please clear me how to navigate between other views/Activities ??

and How to remember which menu item are you on ?

Please help ....

Answer (score 2):

I started my recent project with the Navigation Drawer template as well. As far as I can see it, you have basically two options:

A) Stick with the MainActivity, which you already have and swap out the contents by showing different fragments (add a FrameLayout to the content_main.xml file to do this.) This is what I have done. If you do this, you don't have to worry about the Navigation Drawer at all, because there is only one.

```
private void setFragment(Fragment fragment, String fragmentTag) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setFragment: " + fragmentTag);
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragmentTag);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

B) You can also use the onNavigationItemSelected() method to start a number of new activities as usual. IMHO each of this activities would then have to have its own Navigation Drawer. I haven't tried this, but calling

```
final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    final ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

in each of the onCreate() methods of the activities *should* work. Which item in the menu is currently selected should be passed to the Activity via an Intent.

Cheers

Matthias

Comment: the second solution is the work around. SO there is no direct working ?

Comment: I'd just go with solution A, as solution B is supposed to be bad practice, as I read elsewhere.

Comment: its good , But there is another problem in doing so , and that is back press

Comment: What do you mean? I haven't implemented back press in my app yet. You  can take a look here:  http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

Comment: look I have mainactivity with the 3 fragment. I call the first fragment in the activity , as when the app starts and so the Navigation menu indicates the first item in navigation menu. But when I click the second menu in the navigation menu , its replaces the 2nd related fragment in the main menu. So Now the case starts , at this point when I press back the previous fragment gets replaces in the main activity , here when you will open the navigation drawer , it will still be indicating the second fragment / Second item highlighted.

Comment: I just want that when I press back and it navigate me back to the previous fragment the navigation item also get updated itself.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Implement all the navigation drawer/View working stuff in a separate activity called BaseActivity ot what ever you want.

Step 2: Then extend class with this base class

this is easy way to do it as far as I know.

Comment: but how about if I have to extend the class with other class to implement the working of that thing , For example Yourtube , as we need to extend the activity with YouTubeBaseActivity